# What is going on under the hood for Backbone's extend?

Tags: backbone.js, model, underscore.js, extend

I tried to look through the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) but couldn't find the source for Backbone's extend. Reading [how underscore's extend works](http://underscorejs.org/#extend), it seems like when you do extend, you are returned the destination object with added properties -

> extend_.extend(destination, *sources)  Copy all of the properties in
>   the source objects over to the destination object, and return the
>   destination object. It's in-order, so the last source will override
>   properties of the same name in previous arguments.
>
> _.extend({name: 'moe'}, {age: 50});
>   => {name: 'moe', age: 50}

So, if Backbone is using this #extend method under the hood for Model#extend, then in the below, does that mean that Backbone's Model object just got more properties?

```
var Note = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function() { ... },

  author: function() { ... },

  coordinates: function() { ... },

  allowedToEdit: function(account) {
    return true;   }

});
```

If after making Note, I make a Book -

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function() { ... },

  coordinates: function() { ... },

  allowedToEdit: function(account) {
    return true;   }

});
```

Will book also have a author property that is left over from the make of the Note since that extend added the author property to the Backbone's Model object?

Comment: `Backbone.Model.extend` and friends aren't the same as `_.extend`: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-249

Comment: Note is an extension of Backbone model... Book is an extension of Backbone model... both will get properties of Backbone.Model... But how in the world do you think book is going to get anything from Note? It's not an extension of note or anything.

Comment: because according to underscore's #extend, the note extend added something to Backbone.Model, so then i thought now the Backbone.Model would have extra stuff left for Book